# How can I determine if a generator is internally or externally insulated?

Tags: electrical, generator

I have a TroyBilt 8000 watt generator (model #030247 rev 2). I need to be able to tell my well company whether it's internally or externally insulated so they can get me info about a well pump.

The well company INSISTS that the phrase internally or externally insulated is correct and it does not have anything to do with the ground.

Link to manual:
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1314974/Troy-Bilt-030247.html
How can I determine whether it's internally or externally insulated?

Comment: You could probably find that info in the generator's documentation. If you're not sure how to interpret the docs, if you'll provide the exact model number of the generator ([edit] that into your question) or, even better, a link to the documentation, someone here will help you interpret the docs to get you that info.

Comment: Are you sure that’s what they asked? Insulation (thermal or acoustic) seems very unlikely to matter to a well pump. The most common concern with generators is whether or not they have a neutral-ground bond (which some people may refer to as “isolation” or “isolated”).

Comment: Can you ask your well company why they need this tidbit of information?

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be about isolation/bonding of ground and neutral, or it could be about the transfer switch.

### Grounding

This is the grounding information they may be asking for:

[image]

### Transfer

This is the transfer information:

[image]

Your generator does not have a transfer switch. This switch would automatically disconnect the utility supply so that a generator does not short, draw or feed back into the neighbourhood. Without one you cannot use it to feed building wiring that is also serviced by the utility company. Any equipment must be plugged into it, and this affects how the well is wired to the generator if it is also wired to the house wiring.

Ref: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/511123/Troy-Bilt-030247-1.html?page=10#manual

## More about the Transfer Switch

Here is an example of a transfer switch wired into the house:

[image]

> What Generators Need A Transfer Switch?
>
> Standby generators for homes and businesses almost always need one. Since they are always waiting for when the power goes down, it is important to have this extra piece of equipment to keep the power flowing without downtime.
>
> However, portable generators don’t strictly need a transfer switch, but it is usually a good idea. The biggest benefit of having a transfer switch in a residential setting is that you gain the ability to power things up via your circuit breaker panel instead of having to use extension cords. This includes hardwired devices, such as your dishwasher, hot water heater, air conditioning, and ceiling fans.

Ref: https://www.wpowerproducts.com/news/why-do-generators-have-transfer-switch/

Comment: Some generators have/give you a choice of having a floating neutral or a bonded neutral, usually a simple change of moving a wire.  This might be what the well company wants to know.

Comment: @crip659 yes possible. Now he has a link to the manual and he can check with the well people. But I have suspicion now that this question could also be about the transfer switch, so answer updated.